# Ubuntu For Smartphones

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch

Is there any way i can install ubuntu on my smartphone.
My phone is Samsung wave 3 GT-S8600
It is Bada 2.0 OS
It's firmware is S8600DDLD1/s8600ODDLD1 (INU)

Answer (score 0):

The minimum requirements to install Ubuntu in a phone is it should have Minimum 512 MB RAM and processor should be minimum 1Gz .

as I have seen your mobile having 1.4 GHz Processor & 512MB of RAM. so it's fine.

read this for more information https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

Answer (score 0):

The list of currently supported devices can be found here...

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

Unfortunately your device isn't supported but this ***may*** change in the future.